# Wrong path in img src. React redux app

Tags: image, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is wrong with my path to image? Everything is wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image.jpg` is different from `o.jpg` ... ?

Also, you need to import your image, like this : 
`import theNameYouWant from 'path/to/your/image'`, and then :

`<img src={theNameYouWant} />`

Comment: the same, o.jpg is the previous name, now it is image.jpg